# Was John Christie supposed to return for a later Mission: Impossible episode?

Tags: character, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-tv

In the episode "Spy" (S01E14) of the 1988 run of [*Mission: Impossible*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094511/) the IMF team is tasked with finding and destroying a chemical weapons factory owned by former MI6 agent John Christie and putting an end to his business. Now apart from having previously been "one of their own" John Christie actually stands out from the rest of all the villains in even two more aspects:

1. He is the only one to actually directly uncover Jim Phelps and his team as IMF agents.
2. While they do put an end to his business, he is neither killed nor captured in the process and remains the only villain ever succeeding to escape at the end.

This makes me wonder if he actually was planned to return in a future episode. While he never did so during the entire two seasons, I don't have much insight into any possible casting or writing changes that the 2nd season might have undergone or if there were ever planned more than those two seasons. So **is there any reliable information if there were ever plans to make more out of John Christie's character**, like e.g. letting him return in a future episode (or even making him a kind of "White Whale" to repeatedly evade capture in multiple episodes)? Was he maybe even planned to return for the 2nd season but was then dropped due to external factors? Or was there anything else behind his evasion at the end of the episode?